# wait, and then start again the animation with velocityJS

Tags: jquery, velocity.js

Are there a way for stop the animation, but then start it animation again in the same point that I stopped it?

I know with the method "stop" I can stop the animation,

```
$element.velocity("stop");
```

but with it I can't resume the animation.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the kind of answer you're expecting but, VelocityJS doesn't have a pause/continue like funcionality.

Why? Because Julian Shapiro (the creator of VelocityJS) [choose not to create it](https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/issues/14).